# Python+selenium code works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I wrote a selenium controlled webpage parser in Python 2.7. It works fine in Chrome (v64) and completes the job. However, in Firefox (v58), the webpage opens perfectly fine, but then code generates an error at the  at the first instance of `find_element_by_name`.

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_fastener list.py", line 13, in <module>
    elem = br.find_element_by_name("userId")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 487, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message:
```

The first few lines of the code are as follows:

```
 import urllib
 import os
 import time
 import fileinput
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from formatFilename import formatFilename

 br = webdriver.Firefox()
 br.get("some_url")
 elem = br.find_element_by_name("userId")
 elem.clear()
 elem.send_keys("myname")
```

The error occurs when I try to find the form element "userId". I have placed geckodriver in `/usr/local/bin` folder.

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete error stack trace?

Comment: Do you see an alert on screen?

Comment: @DebanjanB please see the updated error message.

Comment: @Ian No, no on screen errors. Only out of the ordinary thing that I see is firefox's url bar is orange-colored. I guess that is because of selenium control

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any such issue in your code block. It seems to be a synchronization issue. A possible solution would be to induce *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` clause as `element_to_be_clickable` using either of the following options :

- Using XPATH :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@name='userId']"))).send_keys("myname")
  ```
- Using CSS_SELECTOR :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name*='userId']"))).send_keys("myname")
  ```

---

### Update

You will require the following *imports* :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Do I need to include another header for using `WebDriverWait`? It generates an error `NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined`

Comment: ok, now webdriverwait error is solved, but the initial error still persists: `selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message:`